# Regex for URL going to infinite loop using python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I am using this code to detect **URL** using python3:

**Code:**

```
regex = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))"
def replace_urls(text):
#     print("replace_urls",text)
    return re.sub(regex, 'URL_ENTITY', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

At some particular sentence, the regex goes in infinite loop and code keeps running.

Is this correct regex, or something needs to be modified?

**Example where it goes to infinite loop:**

```
x="abc.com/us/help/article/does-abc-cover-my-purchase-if-there's-a-problem-(purchase-protection-for-buyers) for further information about our Purchased Protection Program."
```

Why does it go to infinite loop?

Comment: Maybe you could provide an example for which is fails?

Comment: If you found a case causing catastrophic backtracking you must fix the regex. What is the string? Also, remove `flags=re.MULTILINE`, there is no `^` / `$` anchors in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

First off,  without the same text to test I can't be fully sure this will work.
You can try it to see if it cures the problem though.

There are 2 issues noticed. In one greedy quantified cluster you have a nested quantifier like `(?: A+ | (?: BsomecluseterA) )+`
The other issue is that the final cluster is almost identical to the first,
just a slight variation.

You should be able to undo the quantified quantified clause by just getting
rid of the quantifier.
Then joint the two almost identical clusters and factor out the difference.

The result is this

```
(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]|\((?:[^\s()<>]|(?:\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]?(?<=[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]|\)))
```

then with expansion

```
 (?i)
 \b 
 (                                   # (1 start)
    (?:
       https?://
     | www \d{0,3} [.] 
     | [a-z0-9.\-]+ [.] [a-z]{2,4} /
    )
    (?:
       [^\s()<>] 
     | 
       \( 
       (?:
          [^\s()<>] 
        | (?: \( [^\s()<>]+ \) )
       )*
       \) 
    )+
    [^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]? 
    # might be necessary, might not
    (?<= [^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’] | \) )
 )                                   # (1 end)
```

If this doesn't work, there are assertions and back references that
can be employed to simulate Atomic groups.

---

10/28/2021 solution applied to new sample provided:

```
abc.com/us/help/article/does-abc-cover-my-purchase-if-there's-a-problem-(purchase-protection-for-buyers) for further information about our Purchased Protection Program.
```

https://regex101.com/r/KpIhZz/1

Comment: I have mentioned the example above.

Comment: @MAC -If it helps, I tried out solution on your new sample. Seems ok, link is on the bottom.